# ssh not working after docker installation

Tags: docker, ssh, centos7

I have created a virtual machine which has centos7 installed. I have installed docker CE successfully too using offical docs. After I add my user to docker group, I tried starting the docker service using this command:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

but it gets stuck & I am exited from putty. When I try to login again through putty, it says `connection refused`.

ssh login through putty does not work unless I restart the system.

any suggestions?

Comment: Have you by any chance started a container inside that VM, that 'steals' the port 22, which starts with docker agent?

Comment: @fragmentedreality docker is not starting. so no container is yet open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be the he Docker default bridge (docker0) network conflicts with your internal network hosts access.
Try to configure the default bridge to a different subnet.

Look at [Use bridge networks documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) for details.

May be intersting this post too [How do I configure the default bridge (docker0) network for Docker Engine to a different subnet?](https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-configure-the-default-bridge-docker0-network-for-docker-engine-to-a-different-subnet)

Comment: For those that end up here from Google. I had to create the daemon.json file as @gile points out.